# Merge two LMDB databases for feeding to the network (caffe)

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, lmdb

Here are two LMDB databases. Is there any way to merge these two databases and feed it to network using caffe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply write a script using the python lmdb interface. Something like:

```
import lmdb

env = lmdb.open("path/to/lmdbFile")
txn = env.begin(write=True)

database1 = txn.cursor("db1Name")
database2 = txn.cursor("db2Name")

env.open_db(key="newDBName", txn=txn)
newDatabase = txt.cursor("newDBName")

for (key, value) in database1:
    newDatabase.put(key, value)

for (key, value) in database2:
    newDatabase.put(key, value)
```

or you could just as simply add one to the other by:

```
for (key, value) in database2:
    database1.put(key, value)
```